# where_properties function and like keyword together in ahoy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ahoy

Is it possible to use LIKE keyword and where_properties function together or something similar. Because i need to create query like this.

```
Ahoy::Event.where(name: "$click").where_properties("'href' LIKE '%#{brochure.id}%'").count.size
```

Comment: Hi Emre, please try this:
     Ahoy::Event.where(name: "$click").where("properties -> 'href' like '%#{brochure.id}%'")

Comment: What is the column type for properties? This is actually extremely important when it comes to `#where_properties` as is evident in [`Ahoy::Properties::ClassMethods#where_properties`](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/blob/master/lib/ahoy/properties.rb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

```
 Ahoy::Event.where(name: "$click").where("properties ->> :key LIKE :value", key: "href", value: "%#{brochure.id}%").size
```

fix the query now works as expected.

Comment: I try your solution and it gives errors somethings like this #<Ahoy::Event::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00560ad59dbd78>

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it out.